# how can i trigger event when hidden div get focus in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

In a tabb design If there are multiple hidden div how can i trigger event when hidden div get focus using jquery. I tried "focus" but thats for form controls. please suggest

Comment: I'm merely curious, but why are you trying to set `focus()` on *hidden* elements?

Comment: hidden elements don't get `focus`.

Answer (score 0):

You could supply a callback to the `show()` method, provided you are the one making that call.

```
$('#tab1').show('fast', function(){
    // do something now that it is showing
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to focus hidden field. But I suggest to use opacity as alternative if your existing DIVs code is editable. You can do it something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="hiddendiv" style="height:'200';width:'200'">This is hidden DIV</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#hiddendiv').stop().animate({ opacity: 0.0 }, 500);

$('#hiddendiv').live('mouseenter', function(){
    $('#hiddendiv').stop().animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 500);
});
```

### Demo